# Module tkinter working with python 3.5, but not python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.5, python-3.6

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and have just installed installed python 3.6. via `apt`.
When `import`ing `tkinter`, I get the oft-seen error

```
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package
```

Trouble is, the `python3-tk` package **is** installed.

```
$> python3.5 -c "import tkinter"
[no output]
$> python3.6 -c "import tkinter"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-tk package')
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show that the python3-tk package is installed?

Comment: have you tried re-installing python3-tk?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, several times.

Comment: @EthanField I don't understand. I checked `apt`'s list of installed packages and it also says it's already installed when trying to install it.

Comment: if the tkinter package is already installed have you tried to uninstall tkinter first and then re-installing the 3.6 tkinter release?

Comment: @Mike how would I go about doing that? `apt` only has one version.

Comment: You should be able to find the version information of the tkinter installation you currently have. Then go and download that version. After that it should be as simple as uninstalling and then installing a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by restoring `/usr/lib/python3.6` from backup. I've now seen it several times that when stuff goes missing from there, the package manager cannot reinstall it, despite claiming to do so.